# Store for loop into an array

Tags: c#

I want to store my for loop into an array so I can access the variables in other parts of my code.

I've tried to work through a couple of the solutions from similar threads, but can't get them to work. I'm new to c# and coding. Thank you!

```
double a[] = new double[4]; 

for (double PositionX = 0.0; PositionX <= 12000.0; PositionX += 3000.0)
{
//I want the result of the for loop to be stored back into my array.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use an index:

```
double a[] = new double[4]; 
int index=0;

for (double PositionX = 0.0; PositionX <= 12000.0; PositionX += 3000.0)
{
//I want the result of the for loop to be stored back into my array.
    a[index++]=PositionX ;
}
```

There are loads of ways to do this and lots of ways of declaring, initialisating and incrementing your index.

You could turn it on its head a bit which would be more robust:

```
double a[] = new double[4]; 
int index=0;
double PositionX = 0.0;
for ( index=0; index<a.Length ; ++index )
{
    a[index]=PositionX ;
    PositionX += 3000.0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Store your array index in a variable, to parse through it.

```
  double a[] = new double[4]; 
  int i = 0;
  for (double PositionX = 0.0; PositionX <= 12000.0; PositionX += 3000.0)
  {
        a[i] = [yourvalue];
        i++;
  }
```

Or another way is to use `List`.

```
  List<int> a = new List<int>();
  for (double PositionX = 0.0; PositionX <= 12000.0; PositionX += 3000.0)
  {
        a.Add([yourvalue]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some flaws. The syntax for creating arrays in C# is:

```
double[] arrayName = new double[elmentCount];
```

(So the [] is after the typename not the variable name)

Also you will get an `IndexOutOfRangeException` because the code in the for cycle will run 5 times (0, 3000, 6000, 9000 and 12000 are all less or equal to 12000), but your array is only 4 elements long.

Just to add some knowledge to the other solutions you can also use Linq to generate arrays that contain numbers that have even spaces between them. I encourage you to use linq, because it's awesome. :)

```cs
double[] a = Enumerable.Range(0, 4).Select(x => x * 3000.0).ToArray();
```

Enumerable.Range generates an integer sequence starting with 0 that has 4 elements. Select projects each integer into a double by multiplying it with 3000.0, then ToArray converts the result into an array.

The result is an array that contains 0.0, 3000.0, 6000.0, 9000.0. If you also want to contain 12000.0 then you just have to change 4 to 5.